# How can i include header files from another directory using Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Consider this as my directory structure :

```
- Main_Dir    
         - Dir1
         |      - Dir2
         |      |     - A.h
         |      |     - B.h
         |      - Dir3
         |            - C.c
         - Makefile
```

My requirement is that, i have to only use **#include <Dir2/A.h>** and **#include <Dir2/B.h>** in the **C.c** file to include those header files(but not **#include <Dir1/Dir2/A.h>** and **#include <Dir1/Dir2/B.h>**) using **Makefile**(means that Header files Path can be included in Makefile). Is it Possible to include those headers like that using **Makefile**? If anyone Knows on how to do it using Makefile
or any suggestions to do it without changing the Directory structure Please let me know.

Comment: Since you didn't show us your makefile we can't give you any concrete examples.  But basically you have to add the option `-IDir1` to your compiler invocation, so probably the `CFLAGS` variable in your Makefile.  You're not "telling make" where to look for headers.  You're telling make to _tell your compiler_ where to look for headers.

Comment: If you use clang or gcc, you should use -I option. Something like this: gcc -I. Dir3/C.c

Comment: You need to understand the difference between Make, a tool that knows about file dependencies and the commands to update the files, and your Compiler/Linker, the tool that needs to know the correct paths while executing these commands. Mixing them up leads to frustration.

Comment: From `C.c`, there is no `Dir2/`. That would be `../Dir2/`. Changing directory is not in the C standard, but `..` should be pretty standard on file systems with a hierarchical design.

Answer (score 1):

In your Makefile, it is common to do something like this:

```
CXXFLAGS += --std=c++17 -I..
```

and later:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp
     g++ ${CXXFLAGS} foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

You can have as many -I arguments as you need.